# Trying to use ItemsControl.AlternationIndex to show row index in list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've got the following XAML which is intended to put the row number in the left column but all that gets output is `0`

```
<ListBox 
VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
ItemsSource="{Binding MoineauPumpFlanks.Stator.Flank.Boundary, Mode=OneWay}"
   AlternationCount="2147483647"
   >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
               <TextBlock 
                   Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
                                  Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
                   Margin="0,0,5,0"
                   />

                <!-- A custom control of mine -->
               <Controls:LabelForPoint Point="{Binding}" />
           </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Can anybody suggest what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The below does what I want

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
           Path=TemplatedParent.(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
    Margin="0,0,5,0"
    />
```

Comment: Maybe this binding is better to read: `Text="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}"`.