# WPF AlternationIndex wraps around when moving items to top of list

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I'm trying to make a GridView with a row-number *and* give the user up/down buttons to change the order of the rows. Many posts suggest using AlternationIndex (for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947024/trying-to-use-itemscontrol-alternationindex-to-show-row-index-in-list) ) and that *almost* works perfectly and it handles when the user pushes the up/down buttons to change the order of the rows. But AlternationIndex fails when you move an item to the very first position -- at that point, it ought to show 0 but it instead wraps around to the last value in AlternationCount.

Example:

```
    <ListView AlternationCount="1000" Name="_stuff" Grid.Row="0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn
                               Header="Alit" Width="30"
                               DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" />

                        <GridViewColumn Header="ColumnName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" Width="240"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

and then my code-behind is:

```
 ObservableCollection<string> data = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "First", "Second", "Third", "Forth", "Last" };

 public MainWindow()
 {
      InitializeComponent();
      _stuff.ItemsSource = data;
  }

  private void UpDownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      //User wants to change the order -- remove the item from the observable 
      //collection and reinsert it at the new position.  
      data.Remove("Last"); //First remove, then re-insert.

      //If you move the last item to *middle* of list, it works fine and the index
      //is correct. (All other items are pushed down by 1, like you'd expect.)
      //But move to the *top* of the list and the new index is 999?

      //THIS WOULD WORK FINE AND ALL INDEXES ARE CORRECT
      //    data.Insert(3, "Last"); //Insert to middle of list

      //But this gives an index of 999???? Seems to be wrapping
      //around to the last AlternationCount. But why? 
      data.Insert(0, "Last"); //insert to top of list
  }
```

Any ideas how I can make the alternationIndex of that new item on the top be 0 instead of 999?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a bug. It's not acceptable for it to behave like that. Somehow the `AltenrationIndex` is set wrong, you can find the source code about this but frankly speaking it's not really easy to understand. There is some algorithm behind this involving the virtualizing mechanism as well as pattern they implement. Here is the source code that I think may involve the updating to `AlternationIndex`, the method [SetAlternationIndex](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemContainerGenerator.cs,d2527f9f358d93ed). It's called in some callbacks such as when AlternationCount is changed, item is removed, ...

Some hard-to-understand concepts involved here are `ItemBlock` and `offset` as well as `GeneratorDirection`. That's why it's hard for me to understand the code there.

I post this answer because I've found a simple solution which works although I'm not sure if there is any performance issue with it but I'm pretty sure it should be acceptable.

The `AlternationIndex` should be in order again if the item containers are re-generated. Because in virtualizing mode, the number of item containers are just equal to the number of visible elements, so that's why I think this does not lead to a performance issue. The `ItemContainerGenerator` implements the interface `IItemContainerGenerator` which has a method called `RemoveAll`. By using this method, all the realized (generated) item containers will be removed and they will be auto-generated again causing the `AlternationIndex` to be set in the correct order.

Also, as you said, the problem seems to occur only when the item is inserted at the first index. So we just need to use this trick for just that specific case:

```
private void UpDownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  //before changing any item at index 0 such as by inserting 
  //some new one or even use the method Move(... , 0),      
  //We need to clear all the realized item containers
  var cg = _stuff.ItemContainerGenerator as IItemContainerGenerator;
  cg.RemoveAll();
  //now just proceed the code
  //we can in fact use this instead data.Move(data.Count - 1, 0);
  data.Remove("Last");
  data.Insert(0, "Last");      
}
```

Here is another pretty solution using `ICollectionView.Refresh()` method. You just need to refresh it (but of course should be applied only when that problem occurs):

```
private void UpDownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
  //we can in fact use this instead data.Move(data.Count - 1, 0);
  data.Remove("Last");
  data.Insert(0, "Last");      
  CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data).Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Your first proposal didn't work for me (the rows appeared duplicated each time), but the second proposal of calling ICollectionview.Refresh() seems to do the trick. Thanks!